# How to use canvas inside slideshow (chartjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

I've been trying to find a working example on how to implement a slideshow that wraps n canvas elements. I attempted to create a **very** simple slideshow with my canvases based on an example that used list-items with varying backgrounds instead of canvases.

Based on **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8ydk/1/)** I changed the list elements to this:

```
<div id="slider"> 
    <ul>
    <li> <canvas id="programming"> </canvas> </li>
    <li> <canvas id="design"> </canvas> </li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
var designBarChartData = {
        labels: ["HTML5", "CSS",  "jQuery", "JavaScript", "ASP.NET"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            backgroundColor: ["rgba(255,82,0,1)", "rgba(0,100,255,0.9)", "rgba(255,255,255,0.9)", "rgba(231,131,0, 1)", "rgba(0,122,204,0.8)"],
            borderColor: ['rgba(255,39,0,1)', 'rgba(0,20,255, 1)', 'rgba(0,0,0, 1)', 'rgba(232, 90,0, 1)', 'rgba(0,70,204, 1)'],
            borderWidth: 3,
            yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
            data: [40, 30, 50, 40, 30]
        }]
    };

var langBarChartData = {
    labels: ["Core Java", "C/C++", "C#", "Relational-Databases", "VB.NET", "Erlang", "JavaScript"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Programming',
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(102,61,0,0.9)", "rgba(5,32,74,0.9)", "rgba(176,0,255,0.8)", "rgba(101,0,0,0.8)", "rgba(0,115,255,0.8)", "rgba(146,0,0,0.9)", "rgba(236,211,0,0.8)"],
        yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
        data: [40, 30, 50, 40, 60, 20, 30]
    }]
};
    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("design").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar1 = Chart.Bar(ctx, {
            data: designBarChartData, 
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                hoverMode: 'label',
                hoverAnimationDuration: 400,
                stacked: false,
                title:{
                    display:true,
                    text:"Chart.js Bar Chart - Multi Axis"
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        type: "linear", // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                        display: true,
                        position: "left",
                        id: "y-axis-1",
                        ticks: {
                            max: 100,
                            min: 0
                        }
                    }, {
                        type: "linear", // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                        display: true,
                        position: "right",
                        id: "y-axis-2",
                        gridLines: {
                            drawOnChartArea: false
                        }
                    }],
                }
            }
        }); 
    }; 
        window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("programming").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar1 = Chart.Bar(ctx, {
            data: langBarChartData, 
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                hoverMode: 'label',
                hoverAnimationDuration: 400,
                stacked: false,
                title:{
                    display:true,
                    text:"Chart.js Bar Chart - Multi Axis"
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        type: "linear", // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                        display: true,
                        position: "left",
                        id: "y-axis-1",
                        ticks: {
                            max: 100,
                            min: 0
                        }
                    }, {
                        type: "linear", // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
                        display: true,
                        position: "right",
                        id: "y-axis-2",
                        gridLines: {
                            drawOnChartArea: false
                        }
                    }],
                }
            }
        }); 
    }; 
      Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
```

It seems most examples cover slideshows of images, whereas in my case I want to create a slideshow of charts (chartjs - which uses a canvas to draw the chart on).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M8ydk/433/ please try this ... Hopefully it will help you

Comment: what isn't working for you, placing your code into the fiddle i get this http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/jh4pbmko/ which has two graphs on a slide show. only thing i changed was to name the second ctx var to something new